# fetching text response from the server using jquery file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-callback

My server returns a simple string which I want to alert out and append to a div. So I do the following in [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API)

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'text',
    done: function (data) {
        alert(data)
       $('#result').html(data); 
    }
});
```

I've also tried this variation

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'html',
    done: function (e, data) {
        alert(data)
       $('#result').html(data); 

    }
});
```

however, the alert shows `'Object'` and the `#result` div is not updated with the response. I've seen the response using firebug and he response does infact come from the server and it is simply a string.

**Update**

after some debugging I found this code to be working fine, but not sure if this is the best way to do this.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'text',
    done: function (e, data) {
        console.log("done", data.result);
       $('#result').html(data.result); 

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use FireBug for Firefox, or Chrome, press F12 and place a `debugger;` statement before  the `alert` statement.
Javascript debugger (any of it) will pause on this line so you can explore the value of the `data` variable. It seems to be a structure, not just plain text.